# Displaying an array | Twig

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I'm having trouble returning an array of options from an SQL database. I've tried a few different variations of returning the data, but I can only seem to get single data points returning like radio buttons, input text, etc.

- I have 3 checkboxes in a form: Blue car, Red car, Green car.
- They all save to the database. However, a "1" is been added. eg. [Blue car, Red car, 1] is being stored.
- When I try and return the data to the twig template, it doesn't load anything.
- I'm new to twig and Symfony, and I'm partly learning through existing code which makes it hard for me to troubleshoot sometimes.
- I'm looking for the output to be like this: Blue car (or) Blue car & Red car (or) Blue car, Red car & Green car. Happy for the code to be simplified for this output.

**var**

```
 /**
 * @var string 
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="sel_cars", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
 */
private $sel_cars;

/**
 * Get cars
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getSelcars()
{
    return $this->sel_cars;
}


/**
 * Set cars
 *
 * @param string $sel_cars
 *
 * @return Listing
 */
public function setSelcars($sel_cars)
{
    $this->sel_cars = $sel_cars;

    return $this;
}
```

**output**

```
   {% if item.sel_cars is not empty %}
     {% set sel_cars = item.sel_cars|split(',') -%}
       {% set sel_carsarray = { 'bluecar': 'Blue car', 'redcar': 'Red car', 'greencar': 'Green car'} %}

     {% for row in sel_cars %}
       {{ sel_carsarray[row] }}                                                    
     {% endfor %}

   {% endif -%}
```

Appreciate the help :)

Comment: What does `{{ dump(item.sel_cars) }}` return then?

Comment: Page returns an error. After looking that extension isn't installed. This is actually on a server being used for development at the moment. I'll have to look at how to add that going forward.

Comment: If `sel_cars` is really a string, you could try with `{{ item.sel_cars }}`

Comment: How do you send your entity to the template ? by parameter in `render()` method in your controller ?

Comment: @DarkBee It also loads blank when I just use {{ item.sel_cars }} on it's own, or within and if not empty. I also tried manually removing the "1" from the database just to be sure that wasn't causing an issue. Would that mean the above code is mostly correct and I have an issue somewhere else? It's weird I can get other data working with no problems, but pulling the checkbox data doesn't seem to work. There is one more file that is called class_listing where some reference code is, but that looks more like it's pushing to the database than anything.

Comment: Check your error logs, also enabling the debug extension should show you the syntax/runtime errors you get in a twig templte

Comment: @Hamham To be honest, being a newbie (and my just failed attempts to find it) I can't even answer that. I'm learning through reverse engineering and tutorials at the moment, due to this being specific/timeframe. If you tell me where to find that, I can answer you. I do know there is a lot of {% import file.html.twig %} on pages and the above output code I'm adding directly onto one of the pages.

Comment: @DarkBee - error logs are fine, I'll have to look into debug extension though.

Answer (score 0):

I seemed to have figured it out.

changing all the above output code from

```
item.sel_cars
```

to

```
item.Selcars
```

It now returns the data.